# The sum $M+N$ is closed iff the sum of annihilators $M^\bot + N^\bot$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

[Conway, p. $171 \# 12$ ] If $X$ is a Banach space and $M$ and $N$ are closed subspaces, show that the following statements are equivalent:
(a) $M+N$ is closed.
(b) The range of the linear transformation $x \rightarrow(x+M) \oplus(x+N)$ from $X$ into $X / M \oplus X / N$ is closed.
(c) $M^{\perp}+N^{\perp}$ is norm closed in $X^∗$.
(d) $M^{\perp}+N^{\perp}$ is weak* closed in $X^∗$.

Similarly, in [Brezis](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf) (page 41), the following theorem is proven, which shows (a) and (c) are equivalent.
[image]

But the proof is long and should use the following lemma and corollary.

[image]

[image]

I am curious to know whether Theorems 2.10 and 2.11 from [Brezis](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf) are related to statement (b) in Conway's exercise. Additionally, how could the other equivalences be proven? In addition, this theorem from Conway might be useful:

[image]

Comment: I don't have much time to look at this but I think that the dual of the operator $A \colon X \to (X/M) \oplus (X/N)$ in (b) is given by  $$A^* \colon (X/M)^* \oplus (X/N)^* = M^\bot \oplus N^\bot \to X^*$$ $A^* (m^\bot \oplus n^\bot) = m^\bot + n ^\bot$ for every $m^\bot \in M^\bot $ and $n^\bot \in N^\bot$. Hence $R(A^*) = M^\bot + N^\bot$. Since $R(A) $ is closed iff $R(A^*)$ is (weak-star) closed, you have that (b),(c) and (d) are equivalent.

Comment: (cont) Also, for (a) $\implies$ (b) you can argue as follows: if $Ax_k =(x_k +M) \oplus (x_k + N)\to (x+M) \oplus (y +N)$ then $\|x_k-x+M\|_{X/M} \to 0$ and $\|x_k-y+N\|_{X/N} \to 0$. Let $(m_k)\subset M$ and $(n_k) \subset N$ be such that $$\|x_k-x+m_k\| \le \|x_k-x+M\|_{X/M} + 1/k \to 0$$
and 
$$\|x_k-y+n_k\| \le \|x_k-x+N\|_{X/N} + 1/k\to 0$$
so that $\|m_k-n_k - x+y\| \to 0$. Consequently $y-x \in M+N$ and thus $y=m+n+x$. Hence  $\lim_k Ax_k = (x+m+M) \oplus  (x+m+N) \in R(A)$.

Comment: Thank you! What's an easier way to show that (b)/(c)/(d) implies (a)? @EvangelopoulosPhoevos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \colon X \to (X/M) \oplus (X/N)$ be given by $Ax = (x+M) \oplus (x+N)$. Notice that the range $R(A)$ is closed if and only if whenever $(x_k+M) \oplus (x_k +N) \to (x+M)\oplus (y+N)$  it then follows that $x-y \in M+N$. Moreover, it is generally true that $R(A)$ is closed iff $R(A^*)$ is closed iff $R(A^*)$ is weak-star closed.

Recall that the duals of $X/M$ and $X/N$ can be identified with $M^\bot$ and $N^\bot$ respectively. Moreover, the dual of $(X/M) \oplus (X/N)$ can be identified with $(X/M)^* \oplus (X/N)^*$. Hence,
$$A^* \colon M^\bot \oplus N^\bot \to X^*$$
and for every $x \in X$ one has that
\begin{align*}
 \langle A^* (m^\bot \oplus n^\bot), x \rangle &=  \langle  (m^\bot \oplus n^\bot) ,Ax \rangle 
\\
&= \langle  m^\bot \oplus n^\bot, (x+M) \oplus (x+N) \rangle 
\\
&=\langle m^\bot ,x+M \rangle + \langle n^\bot, x+N \rangle
\\
&= \langle m^\bot, x\rangle + \langle n^\bot, x\rangle 
\end{align*}
thus $R(A^*) = M^\bot + N^\bot .$

---

This shows that $(b) \iff (c) \iff (d)$. It remains to show that $(a) \iff (b)$. Suppose that $M+N$ is closed. To show that $R(A)$ is closed, suppose that $Ax_k = (x_k+M) \oplus (x_k+N) \to (x+M) \oplus (y+N)$. Then $x_k+M \to x+M $ in $X/M$ and $x_k+N \to y+N$ in $X/N$. For each $k \ge 1$ let $m_k \in M$ and $n_k \in N$ be such that
\begin{align*}
\|x_k-x+m_k\| &\le \|x_k-x+M\|_{X/M} + \tfrac 1k 
\\
\|x_k-y+n_k\| &\le \|x_k-y+N\|_{X/N} + \tfrac 1k 
\end{align*}
The triangle inequality implies that $\|m_k-n_k-x+y\| \to 0$ and thus $y-x \in M+N$. This shows that $R(A)$ is closed.

Conversely, suppose that $R(A)$ is closed. To show that $M+N$ is closed, suppose that $m_k + n_k \to x$ in $X$. Since $n_k +N =0 \to 0$ and $n_k +M = n_k + m_k +M \to x+M$ we see that $(n_k+M) \oplus (n_k +N ) \to (x+M) \oplus (0+N)$ and since $R(A)$ is closed, $x-0 \in M+N$.